# How to use soliditySha3 in web3py

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py

I have tested soliditySha3 function with web3js.

```
var msg = web3Infura.utils.soliditySha3("transferPreSigned", mainContractAddress, recepientAddress, tokenAmountWei, transferFee, randomNounce);
```

I want to use it with web3py. How can I use it?

```
web3.soliditySha3() ?????
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=soliditySha3#Web3.soliditySha3):

```
The Web3 class exposes the following convenience APIs.

...

Returns the sha3 as it would be computed by the solidity sha3 function on the provided value and abi_types. The abi_types value should be a list of solidity type strings which correspond to each of the provided values.

>>> Web3.soliditySha3(['bool'], [True])
HexBytes("0x5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2")
```

Comment: but if I use these "transferPreSigned", mainContractAddress, recepientAddress, tokenAmountWei, transferFee, randomNounce on Web3.soliditySha3() it gives me error

Comment: Make sure you're putting everything in Python lists using `[ ]`. `transferPreSigned` must be a type that's defined in your contract's ABI.